# Maintain Application Monitor Placement

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I have 3 TV's all connected to a dedicated PC that's used solely for monitoring things via 3 chrome browser windows, on 24/7. Is there a way to keep all the windows 'stuck' to their designated monitor even when hard turning off the tv(I have a switch to the outlet, so it basically unplugs the TV's[this way they aren't run at night]) Right now if hard power off the TV's and then turn them on they just cascade all the chrome windows onto one TV.

Comment: Try a soft switchoff; right now you're telling the computer the screens are simply no longer there - it will respond by reducing the number of screens to 1 [minimum] & powering back on will not redistribute. Soft-off ***may*** keep the machine aware of the connections.

Comment: yea, soft off does work, but I would really like to be able to do a hard off since I have basically a light switch hooked to the tv's making it more convenient.

Comment: Can't be done, afaik. Hard-off is "gone", no longer present, no longer recognised, 'emergency' reduction to a single desktop.